# How to concat @Url.Action with jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using bootstrap datatables to create a column displaying a link button to redirect to another view, the problem is that I'm getting syntax error from jquery and I'm not beign successful fixing it.

Here is the relevant part where I get the syntax error:

```
return '<button type="button"class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IncidentesDetalle", "ServiciosController", new { Id = "1" })'"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this being returned from a controller action?

Comment: Yes it is, I want to call the method (which returns a View) on the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should change your string to:

```
return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href=\'@Url.Action("IncidentesDetalle", "ServiciosController", new { Id = "1" })\'"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>'
```

Because in your original code single quotes just closed after `href=` and opened before `><i` again. So part of the returning string like `@Url....` became just invalid code. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work:

```
        string path = "'@Url.Action('IncidentesDetalle', 'ServiciosController', new { Id = '1' })'";
        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='location.href="+path+"'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button>";
```

Comment: I already did that, it showed a jquery error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags"

Comment: Your code is wrong as well. You missed single quote after **href=**

Comment: sir you can add it in the above string assignment